# Why does it throw ClassNotFoundException when I build with spring?

Tags: java, spring, maven

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser
```

I use aspect in my project, and when I run it, this exception throws.

But When I remove my aspects, this issue disappears.
Can anyone help with this issue?
Thanks!!!

Comment: can you paste your pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You need `aspectjtools` to your `classpath`

http://www.findjar.com/class/org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutParser
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools

It would be quite easy to add it as `maven`-[dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) with `compile`-scope

Comment: At least for spring 3.2, it needs aspectjrt (almost same url to find it :-) )